# How can I send a Hex value to a specific IP address and port number

Tags: netcat

I am using bash script to send hex values to my network.

I need to send `0001000011050000FF00` hex value to IP: 192.168.1.5 Port# 502 using `netcat`.

I tried

```
$ echo '0001000011050000FF00' | xxd -r -p | nc -l 192.168.1.5 502
```

and it seems to be wrong.

Can you help me with that?

Thank you,

Comment: What did you do to verify that it's wrong? Do you have debug output from the destination port/machine (to show that the message was received but in the wrong format; to show that the message was not received; ...)? Do you have a tcpdump/wireshark trace to show that those bytes were transmitted over the wire? What else? (And, did you read the manual page for `nc` to understand the options you're using?)

Comment: I don't have a debug output printout. I used wireshark to trace the message, but couldn't find  the message in the printout. Does the command $ echo '0001000011050000FF00' | xxd -r -p | nc -l 192.168.1.5 502 looks right?

Comment: If wireshark didn't show the message, that suggests it wasn't put out on the network. What did you do to verify each step of the command is correct?

Comment: I ran nc -v -n -z -w 1 192.168.1.5 502 to see if the port is up. The response was (UNKNOWN) [192.168.1.5] 502 (?) open. There was a lot of messages to the port (502). May be I need to look at the wireshark printout one more time and see if I can find the message.

Comment: After you do that, if you don't see the message, figure out what each command outputs. For example, pass `echo ... | xxd...` to `hexdump -C` to verify it is correctly turned into hex. Then look at the man page for `nc` to see what options *it* expects.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you.